# Multiple join from same view name with another view name

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SF` 
(
    `ref` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `extref` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `portfno` int(3) NOT NULL,
    `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ref`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `SF` (`ref`, `extref`, `portfno`,`content`) 
VALUES ('100', '200', '999','SF1'),
       ('101', '200', '000','SF2'),
       ('102', '201', '999','SF3'),
       ('103', '201', '000','SF4');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SEC` 
(
    `ref` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `extref` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `portfno` int(3) NOT NULL,
    `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ref`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

INSERT INTO `SEC` (`ref`, `extref`, `portfno`,`content`) 
   VALUES ('100', '200', '999','SEC1'),
          ('101', '200', '000','SEC2'),
          ('102', '201', '999','SEC3'),
          ('103', '201', '000','SEC4');

My desired output is as follows as 2 records.

```
Rec 1 ->100,200,999,sf1,100,200,999,sec1,101,200,000,sf2,101,200,000,sec2
Rec 2 ->102,201,999,sf3,102,201,999,sec3,103,201,000,sf4,103,201,000,sec4
```

I need to have the solution that should not run into performance issue.

Comment: Which database are you using? What is the logic/reason behind your desired output? Please explain

Comment: After answering 1st comment, tell me is Rec 1 a Row 1 ?

Comment: This was the scenario and the database is ibm db2..yes rec1 is first row..

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do it with some sort of a cursor. But cursor is not very easy on performance. With cursor just populate some temporary table, should be easy.

Here is how you can do it without cursor

```
select
 sf_odd.*
,sec_odd.*
,sf_even.*
,sec_even.*

FROM (SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY ref) AS rn FROM sf) sf_even
join (SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY ref) AS rn FROM sf) sf_odd
 on sf_odd.rn % 2 = 1
 and sf_even.rn % 2 = 0
 and sf_odd.rn = sf_even.rn + 1
Join (SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY ref) AS rn FROM sec) sec_even
 on sec_even.rn % 2 = 0
 and sec_even.ref = sf_even.ref
join (SELECT *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY ref) AS rn FROM sec) sec_odd
 on sec_odd.rn % 2 = 1
 and sec_odd.ref = sf_odd.ref
```

Comment: Alex am working on the views. And it's not a table.i just want to share the scenario ...